# How to make routing in ASP.NET MVC3 Compatible in both IIS 6 and 7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6, url-routing

I have this code in Global.asax.cs:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Applications", // Route name 
                "Applications.aspx/Find/{appNum}", // URL with parameters 
                new
                {
                    controller = "Applications",
                    action = "Find"
                }, // Parameter defaults 
                new
                {
                    appNum = @"\d+"
                }  // Constraints
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}.aspx/{action}", // URL with parameters
                new
                {
                    controller = "Applications",
                    action = "Index"
                } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }
```

This is tuned to work for IIS 6: notice **.aspx** after **{controller}**

How can i make the same code work on both IIS 6 and IIS 7 without changing any on the IIS side?

Comment: you need to be careful here. if you don't use actionlink, routelink or this kind f stuff to link other pages, you would want to change them like that.

Comment: Thank you! I will for my next project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have other options.

please see the following blog post which is only written for this issue.

Running ASP.NET MVC Under IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 Classic Mode : Solution to Routing Problem : [http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/running-asp-net-mvc-under-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-classic-mode---solution-to-routing-problem](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/47)